# Ruby / Sinatra - redirects without redirect

Tags: ruby, sinatra

In my controller I have the following

```
post "/buy_item" do
    redirect '/login' unless session[:name]

    @owner = Market::User.user_by_name(params[:owner])
    @item = @owner.item_by_id(params[:item].to_i)

    @current_user = Market::User.user_by_name(session[:name])
    if @current_user.buy_item?(@item)
      @current_user.buy_item(@item)
    else
      redirect '/error'
    end
  end
```

when I'm forcing an "`else`" I get correctly redirected to `/error`, but directly after that I get redirected to another page (`/?loggedin=true`). `redirect "/?loggedin=true"` is the last line of the `post "/login"` method. So, it seems that it is calling `POST /login` somehow..

The route for `/error` looks like this:

```
  get "/error" do
    redirect '/login' unless session[:name]

    template = ERB.new File.new($VIEWS_FOLDER + "/error.erb").read, nil, "%"
    template.result(binding)
  end
```

Nothing in `/error.erb` is redirecting, when I call *localhost:4567/error* directly it doesn't get redirected.

Here's the log:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2012 17:15:03] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 303 - 0.0012
>
> localhost - - [03/Oct/2012:17:15:03 CEST] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 303 0
>
> localhost:4567/login -> /login
>
> 127.0.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2012 17:15:03] "GET /?loggedin=true HTTP/1.1" 200 3916 0.0055
>
> localhost - - [03/Oct/2012:17:15:03 CEST] "GET /?loggedin=true
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 3916
>
> localhost:4567/login -> /?loggedin=true
>
> 127.0.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2012 17:15:05] "POST /buy_item HTTP/1.1" 303 - 0.0030
>
> localhost - - [03/Oct/2012:17:15:05 CEST] "POST /buy_item HTTP/1.1"
>   303 0
>
> localhost:4567/?loggedin=true -> /buy_item
>
> 127.0.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2012 17:15:05] "GET /error HTTP/1.1" 200 1609 0.0039
>
> localhost - - [03/Oct/2012:17:15:05 CEST] "GET /error HTTP/1.1" 200
>   1609
>
> localhost:4567/?loggedin=true -> /error
>
> 127.0.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2012 17:15:05] "GET /?loggedin=true HTTP/1.1" 200 3916 0.0063
>
> localhost - - [03/Oct/2012:17:15:05 CEST] "GET /?loggedin=true
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 3916
>
> localhost:4567/login -> /?loggedin=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two redirects inside your route `'/buy_item'`; and in `'/error'` you do not return after the `redirect`.  `redirect` does something to your HTTP header and it is good practice to return after the call, i.e. in both routes `/buy_item` and `/error`:

```
-redirect '/login' unless session[:name]
+unless session[:name]
+  redirect '/login'
+  return nil
+end
```

I have worked on a large Sinatra app and there were a lot of problems with redirect, the above patch should help.  Moreover I recommend you to take a look at the [HTTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3) and make yourself familiar with the [Post-Redirect-Get scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).  To to redirects with custom status code, you can do `redirect '/foo', 303`.